# How to disable stuck ctrl key in software/memory?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, keyboard, keyboard-layout

The ctrl key of my MacBook 6,1, OS X 10.6.8, got stuck by a water hazard. It's recognized as permanently pressed by the system.

Is there any way to tell the system that it is not? I'm thinking of a simple switch in memory or the like: can this be done and how?

*Follow ups:*

1. Disabling ctrl key by using KeyRemap4Macbook mostly solves the problem. However since the remapping is loaded after user login I cannot use the keyboard for typing the initial password on the login screen. Can you force the remapping to be loaded at another runlevel?
2. So now I don't have a ctrl key and I tried using PCKeyboardHack to remap CapsLock to Ctrl_L. This appears not to work probably due to KeyRemap4Macbook overriding the CapsLock remap. Mapping it to Ctrl_R does not work as intended either: whenever pressing CapsLock it fires a CTRL_R event but you can't press any key combinations because the keydown state isn't held.

Any thoughts about solving these issues? Switching to automatic user login should only be considered a last resort ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/index.html.en):

[image]

The remapping is defined in [control.xml](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/core/server/Resources/include/checkbox/standards/control.xml):

```
<item>
  <name>Disable Control_L</name>
  <identifier>remap.drop_controlL</identifier>
  <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
</item>
```

It also disables caps lock if you've assigned it to control in the keyboard preference pane. You could change it to the right control with [PCKeyboardHack](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/pckeyboardhack.html.en).

[image]

Comment: Yay, that did the trick, thank you so much! I have two follow-ups, though, which I will add to the question, but thank you so far, very appreciated.